# How to access a email by id or guid after move to another folder via exchange webservices

Tags: c#, .net, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have a this public folder structure:

```
Test\Incoming
Test\Read
```

I use the following code with `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices Version 2.2`:

```
//Get Email
EmailMessage mailItem = EmailMessage.Bind(service, ItemID, new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties));

//Get UniqueId "FirstID"
mailItem.Id.UniqueId

//Move Email to Incoming\Read
mailItem.Move(destinationFolderID);

//After moving the UniqueId changed to "ChangedID"
mailItem.Id.UniqueId
```

Is there a way to access the moved email by id/guid because the UniqueId isn't constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends where the move is taking place eg if your moving to another folder within the same Mailbox (in the case of Public Folders it may depend where you have multiple public folder mailboxes and those folders are on different Mailboxes) then the Move Method will return the the new Id of the Item so

```
//Move Email to Incoming\Read
NewItem = mailItem.Move(destinationFolderID);

//After moving the UniqueId changed to "ChangedID"
NewItem.Id.UniqueId
```

If your moving it to a folder in another Mailbox then the MoveItem operation won't return the newid and you will need to search for the Item in the new folder using something like the SearchKey or other custom property you set